# Electron auto-updater doesn't exist?

Tags: node.js, npm, auto-update, electron

Very, very confused. I am using the npm package '' as suggested in this electron documentation: http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.33.0/api/auto-updater/#update-requests

This clearly doesn't line up with the npm package, as the object returned by `var autoUpdater = require('auto-updater');` contains none of the methods the docs say it should. NPM package info:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-updater

Are the docs out of date/wrong or are they listing the wrong npm package? I'm probably doing something stupid.

Comment: Make sure you're on the right version of the [docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.4/api/auto-updater/#update-requests), as well. As Rob noted, the package `auto-updater` is not the same `auto-updater` that electron provides to you.

Answer (score 4):

I spent two days of my life behind this. `autoUpdater.setFeedURL()` was throwing errors and I had no clue as to why it was happening. Here's the right way:

1 - Make sure your electron-prebuilt is not too backdated (I was on electron 0.36; Finally used 1.2+ and it all started working)

2 - Use the new code

```
const autoUpdater = require('electron').autoUpdater;
autoUpdater.setFeedURL(releaseDIR);
autoUpdater.on( .....
```

Answer (score 2):

The module you need isn't in npm, and the page you link to does not say it is.

Rather it's an internal module of `electron` and is part of its source code.

See the [electron github repo](https://github.com/electron/electron/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=autoupdater&type=Code) for information on how to use it.

I'd take a close read of the electron [documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/e05804848f98959d63337aacd9047cd579c5b23f/docs/README.md) as well.

Answer (score 2):

The `autoUpdater` module the [doc is talking about](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.3/api/auto-updater/) is an electron module, not a npm one.

So basically, you can just access its API with:

```
const autoUpdater = require('electron').autoUpdater;
```

The rest is up to you (platforms, ect...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when this layer of indirection was introduced, but on the latest version of electron (~3.0.7) you won't find autoUpdater directly in electron, but rather in electron.remote.

So try:

```
const autoUpdater = require('electron').remote.autoUpdater
```